# AttributeError: 'Class' object has no attribute 'propiety' en Python

Tags: python, python-3.7

Tengo la siguiente clase

```
class Components():
    def __init_(self):
        self.p1=1
        self.p2=2
        self.p3=3
        self.p4=4
        self.p5=5
        self.p6=6
        self.p7=7
        self.p8=8
        self.p9=9

    def drawTable(self):
       print(self.p1)


cm=Components()
cm.drawTable()
```

Al momento de declarar la clase y de llamar al metodo el cual me tiene que mostrar una de sus propiedades me manda el siguiente problema

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "source.py", line 20, in <module>
    cm.drawTable()
  File "source.py", line 16, in drawTable
    print(self.p1)
AttributeError: 'Components' object has no attribute 'p1
```

Comment: Te falta un *underscore* en `__init__`. Por ende, no se están inicializando las variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que falta una barra en la declaración de `__init__`.

Como sólo tiene una barra (`__init_`), Python no la reconoce como función de inicialización, por lo que `self.p1=1` nunca se ejecuta. Por tanto, cualquier uso posterior de `self.p1` es un error.

Agrega la barra que falta y todo solucionado.